# Non-user-readable file for sensitive info

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to send a mail via my app, and I got it working but there's one problem. I have to hard code the password. This is my code:

```
            var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@email.com", PASSWORD),
                EnableSsl = true
            };
            client.Send("email@email.com", "email@email.com", "test", "testbody");
            Console.WriteLine("Sent");
            Console.ReadLine();
```

I don't want users to be able to see the password when they decompile the apk. Is there any way to store a variable (Or something like that) to save sensitive information that users will not be able to encrypt/read on any possible way?

Comment: Rule of thumb for apps running on client machines (whether desktop or a mobile device) don't do centralized database access, and don't put anything in them that you don't want users to have access to. So if it's required to authenticate to use, then they need to hit your own server, and have your server do that work on behalf of the client.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Sadly not. Only slow people down.

You probably want to host an API, and send a request to that - which then sends the emails. Then your password is on not in the app. People can still mimic the requests to your API - but then atleast only the emails you want are sent, and you can use some logic like limiting the amount sent by a given user etc.

You can try one of these techniques if you dont think people will try too hard to break it - https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Storing-Secret-Keys-in-Android, but a determined attacker will always be able to get them

Comment: I saw something like a .config file, are you sure that wont work?

Comment: Alright then thanks I will try that out! I'll mark your answer as solution if it works!

Comment: Hello @WoJo. If this has helped you and you have gotten your problem solved, please remember to mark it as the correct answer.